# send_keys :escape / keystroke escape to close modal window

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am automating an application where I will have to close a modal window by sending escape keys. The modal window does not have a close button.

`browser.send_keys :escape` is not working.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Or can you provide sample HTML or an example?

Comment: Thanks Orde.. Resolved the issue with increased implicit wait time.          browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5

Comment: Can you add that as your answer so this question doesn't show up as unanswered? Thanks.